# How to get where a nodejs function is defined programmatically?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a nodejs server (sockjs) not fully developed by me. At a certain point a function is called, but I could go back to where the function is defined (if it belongs to a certain module, official or custom)

There's a programmatical way to know where a certain function is defined?

Answer (score 1):

You should use a debugger. This would allow you to put breakpoints, so you can locate where that specific function is called and go into.

There are plenty of IDEs, I am familiar with Webstorm (the debugger works well).

Comment: I heard about a specific one, called nodeeclipse. Do you know if it is a suitable solution? (I like Eclipse, in general)

Comment: I used nodeeclipse before, but I didn't like it. I had plenty of crashes with it, and I allocated a lot of memory to it. Maybe it's just on my machine, that being said, the debugger worked well.

Comment: I found out nodeclipse was still set on my machine (memory fails sometimes) and I got the function definition. Still, I'm curios about a programmatical way to log a function definition... There must be one. I'll try Webstorm. Thank you very much.